# ASP.NET Core 3.0 with GDI+ on CentOS 7

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, centos7

I have tried to draw number or text string, everything is good on Windows Server since I use GDI+ method "DrawString" to draw text I want. When I publish my web as linux-64 and try to generate image which based on GUI+ DrawSting, all I can see is my strings turn into blocks like below, even numbers and letters.

[image]

I follow the google's instruction to install related fonts then use "fc-list" to check. I still cannot see number or text.

Can anyone help me? Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug on .NET Core 3.0, it could be solved on .NET 3.1
For now, the only way to solved this problem is downgrade to .NET Core 2.2
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41292